# Javascript, passing 'e' to new Function, scope

Tags: javascript

I have a function block which is dynamic and I need to call with either eval or new Function (preferably the latter). I want to pass in the event it was raised from

```
function MyFunc(e)
{
  new Function("OtherFunc(e, 'abcde')");
}
```

I can't see how to do this, I have tried a few things such as bind(this), and with(this) but no joy. It's an unusual thing to want to do hence my confusion.

NB I can see it works with eval but new Function would be better if possible and I get the impression it should be, e.g.
[How to use scope in JavaScript for Function constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913401/how-to-use-scope-in-javascript-for-function-constructor) (second answer)

Any suggestions? Thanks

(Added: Why I want to do this)
I'm using Kendo mobile buttons. I'm moving from this:

```
<button onclick="MyFunc(e)"/>
```

to this

```
<button data-click="Call" data-func="MyFunc(e)"/>
```

this is because onclick is not recommended with Kendo UI on iPhones

Comment: Why must be a `new Function`? I mean, why not call `OtherFunc` directly?

Comment: Surely Kendo provides a better way to hook up event handlers than that.

Comment: The problem is I already have a whole bunch of onclicks, the alternative is to rewrite every button

Comment: I should add that this is just one example, I have different styles of onclick already in, e.g. onclick="MyFunc(e); OtherFunc('a');

Comment: Also (last point), this seems like a safe use of eval. Speed is irrelevant here, I can't see how it could be hacked. I could just use eval but I'd like to understand how to use new Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you have buttons right now with

```
onclick="MyFunc(e); OtherFunc('a')"
```

...and you want to change those to

```
data-click="Call" data-func="MyFunc(e); OtherFunc('a')"
```

...and you're trying to figure out how to write your `Call` function **without** any significant refactoring, continuing to use the strings as you have them now in the `onclick`.

I'm a bit confused by your use of `e` within `onclick` rather than `event`. As far as I'm aware, there's no `e` in-scope for `onXyz` handlers; the event is available as `event`, though. In the answer below, I've assumed `event` in `onclick` but `e` everywhere else; adjust as necessary.

**Within those constraints**, `eval` and `new Function` are indeed pretty much your only option. It's not more evil than `onclick` (which is also `eval` in disguise); `eval` used with strings you control isn't necessarily evil, it's just usually a last resort (kind of like `with`).

Based on [the documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile-button/events), looks like your `Call` would look something like this:

```
function Call(e) {
  var code = this.element.prop("data-func");
  var f = new Function("e", code);
  f.call(this, e);
}
```

That ends up running the code with `this` being the element that was clicked, and with `e` in scope to the code in the generated function.

I **do not recommend this** except perhaps as a temporary measure during proper refactoring, but within the constraints you've given, that's how I see it working. One reason I don't recommend it is that, as with `onclick`, all of your functions have to be globals (because other than the args you pass it, `new Function` only has access to globals), and globals are best avoided like the plague.

Live example (with some workaround for the fact I didn't include Kendo):

```js
// Kendo calls the data-click function with this being something
// other than the element; but the element is available as `this.element`
function fakeKendo(e) {
  Call.call({element: this}, e);
}

function Call(e) {
  // (Using getAttribute instead of Kendo's prop here)
  var code = this.element.getAttribute("data-func");
  var f = new Function("e", code);
  f.call(this, e);
}

function MyFunc(e) {
  snippet.log("MyFunc: e.type = " + e.type);
}

function OtherFunc(arg) {
  snippet.log("OtherFunc: arg is " + arg);
}
```

```html
<p onclick="fakeKendo.call(this, event)" data-func="MyFunc(e); OtherFunc('a')">
  Click me
</p>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that works. It will be a refactoring exercise but I would much rather be able to change one place at a time and have a working product. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the function constructor. Really, really don't. It is `eval` by another name. Use a function declaration instead. That won't break scope or expect to be built up out of strings.

```
function MyTest(e) {
  function callOtherFunc() {
      OtherFunc(e, "abcde");
  }

  return callOtherFunc;
}
```